# It possible to make http request in Angular to url that are only accesible for the host which server the Angular app?

Tags: angular, http

Probably this is a dummy question, but I'm trying to figure if there is any possibilty to solve this problem in a fictional scenario:

I have a secure environment composed by 2 machines. In host A we have the back-end (Flask api) and in host B we have and Angular app. Only host B will expose its port 4200 to make possible to access to the Angular from the world (or maybe from a determined number of allowed IPs).

Is there any way to make this possible? Because the IP of the host A is only accesible from the host B. And, when the Angular app is executed from a external host, the request that it makes to the IP of the machine A can't be executed because it can't reach the host.

Thank you in advance.

Note:

The request in Angular is being done with HttpClien from '@angular/common/http'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Angular is served to the client, the client will need to contact the servers from where the API is reachable. This means that is Host B (do not expose port 4200, do not use `ng serve` for actual production!) will only be able to serve the Angular app, and the API would be unreachable.

You could set it up so that Host B is a proxy for Host A, it will then accept the incoming traffic for the API and relay it under the hood. `Nginx` or `Apache` are both able to do this for you as a `reverse proxy`.

But other then that, there's no way to connect to a host that's unreachable for a client on the web outside of the actual network.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm going to explore what yout comment about reverse proxy.